# Missing gsl/gsl_sys.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, header

I have downloaded the GSL library and unzipped it in a folder called gsl without the version number. I then created a C file called trygsl.c in the same location as the gsl folder.

The content of trygsl.c is simply this:

```
#include <gsl/multimin/gsl_multimin.h>

int main() {
}
```

I issued the following command:

```
$ gcc -I. trygsl.c
```

and got the following error messages:

```
In file included from ./gsl/multimin/gsl_multimin.h:28,
                 from trygsl.c:1:
./gsl/gsl_math.h:23:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sys.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include <gsl/gsl_sys.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The compiler found `gsl_multimin.h` under `gsl/multimin/gsl_multimin.h` but failed to find `gsl/gsl_sys.h` because it is located under `gsl/sys` and not directly under `gsl`

The `tar.gz` file had this structure. Which brings the question:

Should I move `gsl_sys.h` from under the `sys` folder and under `gsl` directly?

Comment: Moving stuff about in a 3rd party directory should never be the solution one goes with. In the case of GSL one does not simply extract it. It needs to be *installed* from the extracted folder. Consult the `INSTALL` file in the folder you extracted.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks. I installed the library via apt-get on Linux Mint and all went well.